# Name not defined while appending

Tags: python, list, printing

I have a task that requires me to print `' a   xxx yy  '` (spaces are included) from the list
`v_niz(['', 'a', '', '', '', 'x', 'x', 'x', '', 'y', 'y', '', ''])`. My code so far is:

```
def v_niz(plosca):
    b = []
    for e in plosca:
        if e == "":
            b.append("")
        if e == 'a' :
            b.append(a)
        if e == 'x':
            b.append(x)
        if e == 'y':
            b.append(y)
    return b
```

but when i try to run the program it says that **name 'a' is not defined**.

Comment: Well… `a` indeed *isn't* defined. Neither are `x` and `y` for that matter.

Comment: Why don't you use `'a'`, `'x'`, and `'y'`?

Comment: Also… aren't you just reconstructing `plosca`? `def v_niz(plosca): return plosca` would do the same thing in the given example.

Comment: I suppose, what you want is actually ''.join(plosca)

Comment: `def v_niz(plosca): return ''.join(map(lambda s: s or ' ', plosca))`?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you start with `b = []` you are just going to create another list.  If you are trying to create a string you should have:

```
b = ""
```

And to append to the end of it, you use the syntax:

```
b = b + "a"
# or the shorthand:
b += "a"
```

Now as for the logic of your method.  You are not appending what you think you are appending.  For example:

```
b.append(a)
```

tries to add some variable `a` to the end of your list `b`.  It seems you wanted to append the character or string `'a'`:

```
# for a list use
b.append('a')
# for a string use:
b += "a"
```

Same goes for `x` and `y`, you need to use quotes around them: `'x'` and `'y'`.  Also you are not going to add a space for:

```
b.append("")
```

You need to actually put the space into the string, otherwise you are just adding an empty string to the end of `b` which amounts to essentially no change in `b`.  You should try:

```
# for a list use
b.append(" ")
# for a string use:
b += " "
```

Factoring in all these changes the rough skeleton of your code should go more like:

```
def v_niz(plosca):
    b = ""
    for e in plosca:
        if e == "":
            b += " "
        if e == 'a' :
            b += 'a'
        # ...
    return b
```

Comment: I was also given a tester to check if my code is correct, and even with the changes the code still won't go through the tester. I don't know what to do..

Comment: It's actually better to keep `b` as a list and then `join` it at the end. Not good to add to strings since they are immutable. Moreover, just use `if e in {'a','x','y'}:`

Comment: But I actually prefer `return ''.join(' ' if x == '' else x for x in plosca)`

Comment: @Chris_Rands I agree, I would use your way there,  I followed OP's pattern to try and bridge the gap in understanding  for the question.

Comment: @DanBorštnar I am not sure what to say about a tester that you have, given that you told me you wanted to print the string above, these alterations will give you a string and get rid of the exception that you were receiving.  Is this a homework question?  You said you need to print the answer, maybe you should print the result instead of returning a string?